# Is the axis of symmetry of electron orbitals arbitrary? Can it rotate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, electrons, hydrogen

The radial wavefunctions of electrons in hydrogen atoms, the electron orbitals or "clouds," is a topic covered in almost any quantum mechanics course or textbook. Something that has always been curious about them to me, but that I have never found a good explanation of, is related to the axis of symmetry that some orbital levels have. For example, the $\psi_{210}$ level orbital has an axis of symmetry that is generally aligned with the vertical axis in most illustrations, such as the following from Griffiths.

[image: Illustration of the psi_210 electron orbital]

Physically, these axes of symmetries seem strange to me. Are they fixed or arbitrary? Say we have a collection of hydrogen atoms in a container (at the appropriate temperature). Do all the atoms in the $\psi_{210}$ level have their axis of symmetry fixed and aligned or, as the atoms are moving around, are the axes "rotating" about the atom? If they are fixed, what are they fixed about?

It makes the most sense to me, intuitively, that they are not fixed, which would imply that the axes should be able to rotate about the atom. However, I have yet to hear of or come across anything that discusses the "rotation" of electron orbitals.

Answer (score 1):

An electron in the $\psi_{n=2,\ell=1,m=0}$ state associated with a hydrogen-like atom will always have the cylindrical symmetry: the state is a $p$ orbital. However, the direction this symmetry axis points is only given relative to a choice of coordinates.

[image]

Picking a different coordinate system allows us to change which orbitals we define as $p_x$, $p_y$, and $p_z$. We usually pick coordinates that place the orbitals of interest on our axes to make solving problems with them easier. But we could also use linear combinations (weighted sums and differences) of the orbitals to describe $p$ orbitals pointing in whatever direction we want.

The story is a little different for higher values of $\ell$, as some of the orbitals have different shapes. For $\ell = 2$, the $d$ orbitals, the $m = 0$  ($d_{z^2}$) orbital is different in shape from the others:

[image]

However, the same principle holds true: we can change our coordinate system and describe any $d$-like orbital as a linear combination of the ones given.